# div class hover, when hover on td

Tags: css

I have a TD field and a div.

```
    <td class="text" valign="top">


                <div class="number_post">#1</div>    
</td>
```

My question is, how can I, when hover on the td .text, change the style of the number_post div, ONLY?

I don't wish to change the style of the .text, when hovering. Only .number_post.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

write like this

```
.text:hover .number_post{
 color :red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is it:

```
.text:hover .number_post {color:#eee;}
```